# Toggle the CSS variable between two colors. (CSS only)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a `.card` class with a CSS variable that has a `white` background color: `--card-bg: #fff;` and `.card { background-color: var(-card-bg); }`.
When you use the `class` in a `div` it will have the background color white but if you have a child with the same class `.card` the idea is to change the color to `--card-bg: #f9f9f9;`. Then if another `div` is put inside these two I want to change it back to white. The intention is for the `.card` class to change the background color between `#fff` and `#f9f9f9` depending on the parent. Could someone help me with that please?

Comment: I think it will be better if you try to add some code or image of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you cannot have 2 distinct values of the same variable at the same time. The solution would be to use two variables:

```css
--card-bg: #fff;
--card-bg-alt: #f9f9f9;

.card { background-color: var(--card-bg); }
.card .card { background-color: var(--card-bg-alt); }
.card .card .card { background-color: var(--card-bg); }
/* ...and so on... */
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but when I have 4, 6 or more divs with parents that have the .card class it becomes cumbersome. You would have to set a lot of rules: `.card .card .card .card {...}` That's not very optimal.

Comment: This is true, but is there a real-life requirement to have 6 (or more) levels of cards?

Comment: Yes! I am in a great project. I mean it has a lot of complexity. However, even though I didn't want to, I will have to use JavaScript to solve the problem.